# ASP.MVC doesn't load jQuery bundle

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have defined a bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"));
```

My layout looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<head id="ctl00_Head1">
    <title>Test</title>
    @*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
<body id="UCG">
    @RenderBody()
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(new function () {
            alert('test');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My View is minimal and insignificant. I have no idea why ASP.MVC (4) doesn't load jQuery using bundles while commented, standard

Comment: try not to use the minified version of jQuery

Comment: What makes you think its not being loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

include the unminified version (jquery-1.8.3.js).
As bundles already minify files, it doesn't work if they are already minified

Comment: he can also write like this: `"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"` then it will be using "normal" version in debug and minified in release and he will be able to upgrade jquery without changing code

Comment: Thank you very much! Very surprising and worth knowing.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$(document).ready(new function () {
            alert('test');
        });
```

With (new keyword is not required here)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            alert('test');
        });
```

Comment: It works with new, although thank you for your advice.